# Move resources between tenants in different organisations in Azure

Tags: azure, migration

Is it possible to move resources between tenants in Azure, that sit in different organizations?

We have purchased a company that also uses Azure, and their resources sit in a separate tenant. How can we in the quickest way possible move the resources to our tenant?

Right now we have a script that exports the ARM templates, but it requires manual manipulation. It would be easier to somehow just change the name of the tenant to our tenant. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Moving their subscriptions to your tenant is possible. Things related to authentication/authorization especially can break, e.g. Managed Identities. There might be some other things that break as well..

Comment: Can you please clarify how this is done, when their tenant sits in a totally different organization.

Comment: Check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription